# create objects on MSSQL and Oracle from SQLAlchemy Metadata with different casing for names

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, sqlalchemy

I need to take a SQLALchemy metadata object and create on MSSQL and on Oracle. This is easy enough in SQLAlchemy core, see the example below. But the names of objects should be mixed-case on MSSQL and default case on Oracle (all-caps). Its ends up mixed on Oracle as well, which is expected when the names in metadata are mixed. Manually it is trivial, just have separate metadata definitions, but this defeats the purpose of having one set of metadata. Sqlalchemy is 1.3.8, python is 3.7.4.

```
"""
Create from metadata on MSSQL and Oracle
"""
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import, unused-wildcard-import

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=xxx\\xxx;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=yes"
)
print("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
mssqle = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, echo=True)
oraclee = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://@xxx", echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()
t1 = Table(
    "TableNumberOne",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("ColumnNumberOne", String(50), index=True)
)
metadata.create_all(mssqle)
metadata.create_all(oraclee)
```

I can get away with this. I am not sure it covers every possible situation.

```
for _tab in metadata.sorted_tables:
    _tab.name = _tab.name.lower()
    for _col in _tab.columns:
        _col.name = _col.name.lower()
    for _con in _tab.constraints:
        if _con.name is not None:
            _con.name = _con.name.lower()
    for _idx in _tab.indexes:
        if _idx.name is not None:
            _idx.name = _idx.name.lower()
```

Comment: This is also being discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5126).

Comment: Discussion on github is now closed.